# shell script exception from java

Tags: java, shell

I am trying Spring batch job that run from shell script sh file. The following is my code.
**I want to catch shell script exception or error from java code.**

```
String file = "script.sh";
File shellScriptFile= new File(file);
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(shellScriptFile.getAbsolutePath(), "Argument-ONE" , "Argument-TWO");
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache commons exec library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/) for this.

Example :

```
package testShellScript;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException;

public class TestScript {
    int iExitValue;
    String sCommandString;

    public void runScript(String command){
        sCommandString = command;
        CommandLine oCmdLine = CommandLine.parse(sCommandString);
        DefaultExecutor oDefaultExecutor = new DefaultExecutor();
        oDefaultExecutor.setExitValue(0);
        try {
            iExitValue = oDefaultExecutor.execute(oCmdLine);
        } catch (ExecuteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("Execution failed.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.err.println("permission denied.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        TestScript testScript = new TestScript();
        testScript.runScript("sh /root/Desktop/testScript.sh");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. For me all answer is very useful for me. So I notify to all with +1. By the way thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you read [accepting answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

Sripts or external commads usually set an error code. You can get it by using [Process#waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) and handle the returned value according to your needs. A return value of `0` is usually means `no errors`

```
Process process = processBuilder.start();
int exitCode = process.waitFor();
switch(exitCode) {
    case 0:
        // everything is ok
        break;
    case 1:
        // handle
        break;
    // and so on ...
    default:
        // default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Peharps you could use this code snippet:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    String[] cmd = { "/bin/sh", "-c", "script.sh" };
    BufferedReader bri = null, bre = null;
    int exitC = 0;
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        exitC = p.waitFor();
        bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);               
        }
        while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bri.close();
        bre.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    System.out.println("Exit Code: "+ exitC);
}
```

Or if you want to you use processBuilder.start()

```
    String file = "script.sh";
    File shellScriptFile= new File(file);
    Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(shellScriptFile.getAbsolutePath(), "Argument-ONE" , "Argument-TWO");
    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        int exitC = process.waitFor();
        BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine = "";
        while ((inputLine = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        }
        BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        String errorLine = "";
        while ((errorLine = bre.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(errorLine);
        }
        System.out.println("Exit Code:" + exitC);
    } catch (IOException e){
        //captured Exception Here
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The difference is that ProcessBuilder.start() checks if it is a valid operating system command, those valid commands are system-dependent